# Symfony 1.4 user attributes reappears after removing in async ajax request

Tags: php, session, symfony-1.4

In Symfony 1.4, I am trying to show particular text when there is 'a' user attribute. On page reload I am making an async Ajax call that returns shouldDisplayText and  deletes that user attribute but on page reload user attributes reappears sets shouldDisplayText to true and deletes the user attribute again and it keeps reappearing on every page refresh. If I were to make a request with browser or console or even debug, attributes doesn't appear back.
What is it about async call that makes user attributes to come back?
I have checked with logs that it does hit the remove attribute part of code on page refresh.
Not looking like its browser caching. Is happening in different environments/machine.
Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Made sure each Ajax call is hitting the function that removes the user attributes, verified with logs and debug.
After multiple refresh it does not appear back but there is no caching happening anywhere.
Been stuck for few days now.

Comment: I cannot help you with your problem, but I can tell you that an “async ajax” request is just a standard HTTP request if it makes it to the server.

Comment: yes, I am aware of it being standard HTTP request but somehow in symfony 1.4 async call vs browser call is different when it comes to updating user attributes.